# Get value from a list of properties / map

Tags: css, less

Currently, I've a list of colors (for example):

```
@colors: {
    base:    #716aca;
    brand:   #716aca;
    danger:  #c14549;
    warning: #ffb822;
    success: #34bfa3;
    primary: #5867dd;
    black:   #000000;
}
```

I have `each` function that iterates over all the colors and makes all the possible rule colors that we can use:

```
each(@colors, .(@value, @key, @index) {
    .rules-here-@{key} {
        attribute: @value;
    }
}
```

What I can't make work is something like this:

```
.getColor(@color);
```

Where I would use on other places, like:

```
div.system-warning-notification {
    background-color: .getColor('base');
    color: .getColor('danger');
}
```

I have no idea if this is even possible. I have been losing my mind over this for over a week now without any progress.

If that isn't possible, can I generate the variables so I can access them like:

```
@color-base: #716aca;
```

Without having to manually create them?

Thank you very much and I hope I asked this right. I am new here.

Comment: It's `@colors[base]` if you need a value of a property directly by its name, or '`@colors[$@var]` if you need to get it indirectly, i.e. when the property name of interest is specified by a value of some variable (`@var`).

Comment: *I have been losing my mind over this for over a week now* - just for reference: http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature

Comment: Thanks seven! It worked like a charm. I can even do things like `#themes.blue[base];` now :)